# Unable to run vagrant up due to Vbox error (MS 81.)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vagrant, windows-8.1

I am on Windows 8.1
When i attempt to install vagrant and run it with virtual box i always get the following error.

> "The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
>   'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
>   reason is shown below:
>
> Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed.
>   Vagrant uses the `VBoxManage` binary that ships with VirtualBox, and requires
>   this to be available on the PATH. If VirtualBox is installed, please find the
>   `VBoxManage` binary and add it to the PATH environmental variable."

I have tried different things such as uninstalling both virtual box and vagrant and re-installing them.
I have tried installing vagrant first then vbox and the other way around also but no change.

I am new to vagrant so if anyone can assist please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet that you're using the latest VirtualBox version (4.3.12). If so, there's a known issue which will be addressed in Vagrant 1.6.3:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3852

As a workaround you can install VirtualBox 4.3.10 and it will work flawlessly.

Comment: Changing the Windows variables is a better option. Vagrant can be installed to the latest version with this.

Answer (score 4):

As Emyl said, you can either downgrade your VirtualBox or upgrade your Vagrant to 1.6.3(as the issue has been fixed in this version).

But if you want to have a quick fix on this issue you can simply change the environmental variable name for the Virtual Box installation path from `VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH` to `VBOX_INSTALL_PATH`

(This PC -> Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables -> Search for `VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH` and change it to `VBOX_INSTALL_PATH`)

Make sure to restart your terminal before doing `vagrant up` again.

You are done!

Comment: Won't changing the environment variable stop virtualbox functioning properly? I think you should probably create `VBOX_INSTALL_PATH` as a new environment variable that points to `VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH`, as mentioned here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3852

Comment: The variable change option is working for me at Windows 8.1 with a basic installation. A reboot is required ofcourse.

Answer (score 3):

changing VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH and change it to VBOX_INSTALL_PATH in environment variables and then restarting terminal resolved my issue :)

Comment: Don't forget to restart your PC after you're doing this, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem on Windows 8.1 and solved it by restarting my computer. If you have just installed VirtualBox, you may need to restart your command prompt or Windows for the environment variables to get read correctly when you run "vagrant up".

Answer (score 1):

i had to run the cmd.exe as administrator to make this work after using Sri Harsha Kappala solution